# How do I break the infinite redirect loop I've created in Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, url-routing, dynamic-routing

This application is being hosted on S3, entirely static (using `next export`), and we're routing all 404 errors to `index.html` in order to let those be handled on the client side so we can take advantage of dynamic routing. To handle this, I have the following in my `_app.tsx` file:

```
const { asPath, pathname, ...router } = useRouter();

// check if redirect
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname === '/' && asPath !== pathname) {
      router.replace(asPath, undefined, { shallow: true });
    }
  }, [asPath]);
```

This works, for the dynamic routing aspect, but it introduces a new bug: when I navigate to a page that actually doesn't exist, like `/fffff`, there's an infinite loop of the app trying to reroute to `/fffff`. Ideally, it would only try to reroute once, and then default to the `404.tsx` or `_error.tsx` page. I've tried creating a stateful boolean like `hasRedirected` and then just marking that as true in the `useEffect`, but that didn't work because the page is actually refreshing and thus resetting state on each `router.replace` call. How do I handle this error and break out of the loop?

update: The issue seems to be that when I call `router.replace`, Next doesn't find a path to match `/fffff`, so its default behavior is to try asking the server for the route by refreshing. I need to disable or intercept this behavior somehow.

Comment: Does this happen locally too? If so, I’d suggest removing the AWS related tags as they would have no impact on the answer to this question.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary this does not happen locally since it depends on our S3 configuration serving up `index.html` on 404.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question entirely, but if you want to simulate state in a restful application, you can just use something like query parameters. i.e., instead of trying to set some flag to true, just reroute the user to /some/path?hasRedirected=true, or however you'd like to encode your query parameters. Then you can use the query parameters in the routing logic.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer That's a good thought. I actually ended up finding a solution; I'll post it as an answer, but it's essentially that same idea except with session storage instead of query params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we ended up finding, which works quite well, uses session storage to store a `hasRedirected` variable that gets deleted after being read. Here's the code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (router.isReady) {
    const isRedirect = pathname === '/' && asPath !== pathname;
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('hasRedirected')) {
      sessionStorage.removeItem('hasRedirected');
      if (isRedirect) router.replace('/404');
    } else if (isRedirect) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('hasRedirected', 'true');
      router.replace(asPath);
    }
  }
}, [asPath, pathname, router.isReady]);
```